# What's my next step to trace this error message in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

My app started throwing these errors. I'm not sure I understand why.

```
Exception went uncaught:
{ stack: undefined,
  arguments: [],
  type: 'stack_overflow',
  message: [Getter/Setter] }
```

What's my next step to get to the bottom of what is causing this error and why?

UPDATE: Here's error when not catching at root level:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
undefined
```

Comment: are you catching the exception at the root level?  For debugging usually I let the process crash, because you get more information, like what line number the error occured on.

Comment: Check for infinite recursion, you might have an idea where this might occur. The stack is trashed so you are not going to get a trace.

Comment: @hvgotcodes: I am, but only because the crash error was so unhelpful (to me, but perhaps not you). Thank you for the question. I've updated mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it definitely appears to be a case of infinite recursion. Here's some buggy code I wrote:

```
function foo(x) {
  foo(x+1);
}

foo(0);
```

And the resulting exception thrown:

```
node.js:181
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
undefined
```

Looks kind of familiar. Once the stack is trashed, so is the trace. I am afraid the solution involves some good old code review.